# Access value of a pointer in dynamically allocated memory

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

My assignment is to read words from a text file and store them in character arrays which are stored in an array of `char*`. All memory in these arrays needs to be dynamically allocated.

What I am doing is reading in each word with `fscanf()` and storing it into the variable `str`. I am then calculating the length of the word in `str` and dynamically allocating memory to store the value of `str` in the character array `new_word`. `new_word` is then inserted into the array of `char*` named `words`. When `words` runs out of space, I double its size and continue.

My problem lies in the commented code starting on line 62. I'm going to need to read these words later from `words`, so I'm testing my ability to access the pointers and their values. I can index `new_word` fine (in the lines above), but when I then store `new_word` in `words` and try to read from `words`, I get the following error:

`hw1.c:63:25: error: subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector
                while (*(words[count])[k] != '\0'){`

on lines 63 and 64. I know it has something to do with dereferencing the pointer, but I have tried a bunch of variations with no success. How can I fix this?

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    if (argc != 3){
        fprintf(stderr, "Incorrect number of arguments\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    char* infile = argv[1];
    FILE* finp = fopen(infile, "r");
    if (finp == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open input file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    char* prefix = argv[2];

    int count = 0;
    int size = 20;
    char* words = calloc(size, sizeof(char));
    printf("Allocated initial array of 20 character pointers.\n");
    char* str = malloc(30*sizeof(char));

    while (fscanf(finp, "%s", str) == 1){

        if (count == size){
            words = realloc(words, 2 * size);
            size *= 2;
            printf("Reallocated array of %d character pointers.\n", size);
        }

        int i = 0;
        while (str[i] != '\0'){
            i++;
        }

        char* new_word = malloc((i+1)*sizeof(char));

        int j = 0;
        while (str[j] != '\0'){
            new_word[j] = str[j];
            j++;
        }

        new_word[j] = '\0';

        int k = 0;

        while (new_word[k] != '\0'){
            printf("%c", new_word[k]);
            k++;
        }

        printf("\n");

        words[count] = *new_word;

        /*k = 0;
        while (*(words[count])[k] != '\0'){
            printf("%c", *(words[count])[k]);
            k++;
        }

        printf("\n");*/

        count++;

    }


}
```

Comment: `int i = 0;
        while (str[i] != '\0'){
            i++;
        }` Ever heard of `strlen`? Do not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Suggest `char* words` should be `char* words[]` and various code changes to support that.

Comment: `int j = 0; while (str[j] != '\0'){ new_word[j] = str[j]; j++;}`. Use `strcpy` or the _secure_ version of it `strncpy`.

Comment: Since `new_word` is dynamically allocated, anyway, just use `strdup`, that takes care of both the `malloc` and `strcpy` in one instruction.

Comment: @ColeCameron `strdup` is not part of C, which can be a viable reason to avoid it.

Comment: @FelixPalmen If not running in a POSIX-compliant environment, that's true.

Comment: @ColeCameron, Felix is right regardless of environment.  `strdup()` is not part of C, it is part of POSIX.  It may be provided by some other environments, too, but that changes nothing.  The distinction is very important if you want to write portable code.

Comment: @JohnBollinger this is a homework assignment. The goal is a working program with an emphasis on source code readability. Portability is very likely a secondary concern, if it's a concern at all.

Comment: @ColeCameron, it is *never* to soon to be concerned about and to teach about portability.  Moreover, it is not helpful to muddy the waters for those obligated to do homework, even if *right now* they don't need to appreciate the distinction between what is part of C itself and what is specified elsewhere.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I don't disagree, inasmuch as teaching portability is one of the goals of this particular assignment. The distinction between ANSI C and the POSIX C libraries doesn't seem to be this particular student's issue so much as understanding pointers and types in C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, dissecting that a bit:

```
char* words = calloc(size, sizeof(char));
```

this should probably read:

```
char **words = calloc(size, sizeof(char *));
```

Why? What you want here is a pointer to an array of pointers to `char` ... words points to the first `char *`, which points to your first "string".

---

```
char* str = malloc(30*sizeof(char));

while (fscanf(finp, "%s", str) == 1){
```

Buffer overflow here. Make sure to read at maximum 30 characters if you define your buffer not to hold more. Btw, just for convention, call your buffer `buffer` or `buf` (not `str`) and there's really no need to dynamically allocate it. Hint: Use a field size for `fscanf()` or, even better, some other function like `fgets()`.

---

```
    if (count == size){
        words = realloc(words, 2 * size);
        size *= 2;
        printf("Reallocated array of %d character pointers.\n", size);
    }
```

The realloc here will not work, should read

```
        words = realloc(words, 2 * size * sizeof(char *));
```

You need to multiply the size of a single element, which, in this case, is a pointer to `char`.

---

No guarantee this will be all errors, but probably the most important ones. On a sidenote, `strlen()` and `strncpy()` will help you stop writing unnecessary code.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks! I'm getting the output I need now. However, I'm confused by the `realloc()` correction that you suggested. I tried both my original statement and your corrected one, and I'm getting identical output. I guess I just want to know what the difference is and if there is a way to check how much memory has been allocated for `words` (I tried to use `sizeof(words)` and I just get 8 (the size of a `char*`)).

Comment: Please note that this isn't *technically* portable, because `NULL` is not guaranteed to be represented by all-zeroes in memory (e.g., it might be `0xFFFFFFFF` or `0xDEADBEEF` or anything else). Although it's usually not a problem in practice, for max portability, initialize the array manually.

Comment: Assuming a typical 32bit architecture, `sizeof(char *)` will be 4 because a pointer needs 4 bytes. Say `size` is still `20` and you're hitting the 21st string, then your original line will change the size of the memory `words` points to to 40 bytes. Correct would be 160 bytes.

Comment: This will often not lead *directly* to observable problems, but you will corrupt the structure of your heap, leading to hard-to-debug crashes later (because you write outside the allocated region). There are tools for debugging such things, for example "valgrind".

Comment: Is there a C function that will tell me how many bytes have been allocated for `words`? If not, do I need to use a tool like valgrind to find out?

Comment: @MattFenlon, no, there is no function that can tell you how many bytes were allocated to the region pointed to by a given pointer, at least not in the standard library.  If you need to know then you have to keep track for yourself.

Comment: @MattFenlon in general, you don't want to know, that's what `sizeof()` is for. (on amd64, `sizeof(char *)` would be 8). What you *want* to know is how many elements your dynamically allocated memory is able to hold, and you already know that, doing the right thing by keeping track of it in your `size` variable. For `malloc()` and friends, you just multiply that by the element size you get from `sizeof()`.

Answer (score 1):

A pointer to "A [dynamically-allocated] array of `char*`" would need to be recorded in a variable of type `char **`.  That is, a pointer to the first element of the array, which element is of type `char *`.  Thus ...

```
char **words;
```

If you want to have sufficient space for `size` words, then you could allocate it as ...

```
words = calloc(size, sizeof(char *));
```

(note the difference from your code), though it's harder to make a mistake with this form:

```
words = calloc(size, sizeof(*words));
```

Note in that case that the `sizeof` operator does not evaluate its operand, so it does not matter that `words` is not yet allocated.

Most importantly, be aware that the elements of array `words` are themselves *pointers*, not the ultimately pointed-to strings.  Thus you assign a new word to the array by

```
words[count] = new_word;
```

(Again, note the difference from your version.)  Other adjustments are needed as well.

The problematic `while` loop, though, is not fixed even then.  Remember that the expression `pointer[index]` is equivalent to `*((pointer) + (index))`, so the expression `*(words[count])[k]` attempts to *triply* derference `words`.  Even with the type correction, you want only to doubly dereference it: `words[count][k]`.

But why re-invent the wheel?  As Olaf observed with respect to `strlen()` and some of your earlier code, C already has perfectly good functions in its standard library for dealing with strings.  In this case ...

```
printf("%s", words[count]);
```

... would be so much simpler than that while loop.

Comment: good addition for spotting the `*(words[count])[k]`, too ... this one escaped me in my review :)

Comment: I guess I've just been hesitant to use built in C functions because of these dynamic allocation constraints. I don't want to use static memory when I shouldn't be which is leading to these over-complications. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MattFenlon, the standard library functions work for dynamically-allocated strings exactly as they do for statically allocated ones (including their reliance on string termination).  In fact, they cannot tell the difference.